# Redirect sereral functions outputs to results

Tags: redirect, emacs, org-mode, org-babel

When work in source code of python,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session test :results output
print('testing1')
print('testing2')
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: testing1
: testing2
```

Set `:results` as output and then get 2 results,

Try elisp

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp  :results output
(+ 21 35 12 7)
(* 25 4 12)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
```

How could get elisp codes redirect outputs to results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those source blocks have different behaviour -- your python code prints to `stdout` while the elisp just evaluates expressions.

An equivalent elisp block might be

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results output
(princ (+ 21 35 12 7))
(print (* 25 4 12))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 75
: 1200
```

If you want to capture the results of both expressions, you could wrap them in a list,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results value verbatim
(list (+ 1 1) (* 2 2))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: (2 4)

#+BEGIN_SRC python :session test :results value verbatim
1 + 1, 2 + 2
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: (2, 4)
```